# Regex Match for @ Symbol

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make Regular Expression match for '@' symbol in C#. It will check the textbox for @ value only i.e. textbox should contain only @.

Following is my code which is not working:

```
var atTag = Regex.Match("@");
if(atTag.Success)
```

Comment: Why not compare equals?

Comment: If course it doesn't work.. because it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't compile:

```
var atTag = Regex.Match("@");
```

You need to have an instance of `Regex`.

```
var myRegex = new Regex("^@$");
var atTag = myRegex.Match(myTextbox.Text);

if (atTag.Success)
{
    // Oh joy, a match!
}
```

But why make it hard on yourself?

```
if (myTextBox.Text == "@")
{
    // match
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use anchors so it won't match anything except `@`:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^@$");
```